# Do mods know the question banning algorithm?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I know that the question banning algorithm is super secret and all, but I am curious as to whether or not mods can at least see some general information regarding how close someone is to becoming un-banned.

I ask because I have been banned for a while now, and I admit I asked some low-quality questions, but I feel the reason I was banned was because I wasn't familiar with the nuances of the banning algorithm (didn't even know I could get banned).

I was quick to delete questions rather than try to salvage them and now I realize this was hurting me. I wish I could go back and fix my old posts, but they are gone now.

I feel I have contributed positively since my ban and have, in general, become a much different user since I got banned.

I would like to ascertain some information as to whether or not my account is salvageable at this point. I really have fallen in love with the SE network and this site would probably be one of my most useful resources if I could actually use it for purposes other than answering the questions of other beginners.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your help guys, I'm actually no longer banned!!  ( ͡ᵔ ͜ʖ ͡ᵔ )

Comment: Question/answer bans are automatic, not controlled by mods.  [This would be a good place to start](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1079354) for some more information on the matter.

Comment: I know that, I'm just asking if moderators can see how close you are to being freed from the ban

Comment: I would imagine not, as the details of the algorithm are kept internal.

Comment: You can request that old questions are undeleted for you if you want to try and salvage them.

Comment: how would I do that? just pick a moderator and ask them specifically? or post a meta-discussion? or is there a more formal process?

Comment: @LukeP Here are all of your deleted questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23377831) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23462813) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23480474) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23500932) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23795706) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23958275) - A few of them are just blatantly off-topic and I don't see how you could salvage them. If you want any of them undeleted, let me know.

Comment: @animuson #3 could actually be pretty interesting, because I was not allowed to use JS client side, I just never reflected that in the question.                    I believe #4 was so heavily down voted because I posted before putting my code in (I had to go) and the post originally had grammar issues.                                  I think I can possibly salvage these.       Could you wait to un delete until I finish editing them though? I will post another comment

Comment: @animuson I'm still not sure if 3 is salvageable, but what do you think about 4? It only got downvoted because at the time of posting, it had bad formatting and didn't include code, but this is fixed now.

Comment: From what I'm looking at, the only truly off-topic/unsalvageable ones are 2, 5, and 6.  1 seems reasonable (it even has reasonable answers to it).  3 could use some editing help.

Comment: @Makoto I think you're right, It just isn't a smart question (if you read the "DOUBLE-EDIT" you can see what I mean, although I could slightly rephrase it to mention buffering.     As for 3, it is really just a dumb question and I am having trouble remembering the frame of mind I was in when I posted it

Comment: Ping animusion once you have finished editing and decided for sure which ones you want to get undeleted. Take your time, no need to hurry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can only see whether or not a user is banned at the time of viewing their profile. No other information is made available to us. In particular, we cannot see if a user is *close* to getting banned if they are *currently not banned*, and vice versa. We also cannot do anything directly to lift a ban except, possibly, linking to deleted posts where appropriate so that you can edit them, and offering to undelete them (as animuson has done in the comments). While doing so may push you out of the ban if you're right on the edge, we cannot make any guarantees.

If you're still having trouble, you can always [contact the staff](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and explain your case.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is coming directly from a moderator.

Comment: To add to this, don't fixate on mistakes if there are unsung triumphs to be had... For all but the most desperate cases, upvotes and edits on *not-deleted* questions matter as much or more than the presence of deleted questions. So moderators - and anyone else - can help to lift a ban by improving and upvoting reasonable questions on an account even if no one touches closed/deleted questions.

Answer (score 2):

No; the details of the algorithm are secret and are only known by a few Stack Exchange employees. Bans are automatic, so, while adjustments can be made to the algorithm, it mostly works on its own.

As you've stated, it's a bit difficult to get out of a question ban without knowing why you're in one, but you also can't really game the banning system if you don't know how it works, which is the purpose of keeping it secret. So, while [there are some tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) that can help you get out of the ban, the exact details are kept under wraps to prevent against that latter case.

Getting a ban can be difficult, but the key thing here is to try to salvage as many of your old questions as you can and hope for the best.

> I would like to ascertain some information as to whether or not my account is salvageable at this point.

As for this, you *could* create a new account and start over if you really feel that you can't pull yourself out of the ban, but you'll be limited to 1 question per week by your IP address until you have proven that your questions are up to par.